# Java : Lifo Compensation Method

Tags: java, linked-list, lifo

Is there an easy solution to implement LIFO solution based on Java?

For instance I have the following

In (50,150,200)
Out (all after all the inputs) (250,80)

The results should be something like this:

Initial - Final
200 - 200
200 - 50
150 - 80
150 - 20
50 - 50 (Remaining)

Many thanks in advance,

I thought about LinkedList:

```
 if (outList.getFirst()>inList.getLast()){
                                        def pieces = outList.getFirst()-inList.getLast()
                                        valoreFinal.add(inList.getLast())
                                        valoreInitial.add(inList.getLast())
                                        iList.removeLast()
                                    }
```

And so on, but I dont this this is the optimal solution.

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

The Deque object is meant as a LIFO type Stack.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html

It supports both LIFO and FIFO implementations.

LIFO would be implemented with the addFirst(x) and removeFirst() methods.